# Extract companies' register number in Python by getting the next word

Tags: python, regex, string, extract

I am trying to get the German Handelsregisternummer (companies' register number) which usually is directly written behind the word `HRB`. However there are exceptions which I would like to catch with my regex. The goal is to call the function and set the keyword (in this case it is `HRB`). Then the function returns the number. Please see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9fnOZI/2)!

This is what I have so far!
This doesn't catch all cases.

```
def get_company_register_number(string, keyword):

  reg_1 = fr'\b{keyword}\b[,:|\s]*(\w+)' 

  match = re.compile(reg_1)
  company_register_number = match.findall(string) # list of matched words

  if company_register_number: # not empty 
    return company_register_number
  else: # no match found
    company_register_number = []

  return company_register_number


string = "HRB: 21156"
get_company_register_number(string, 'HRB')
>>>>>> ['21156']
```

Comment: Your regex result returning method looks too verbose: if `re.findall` does not find any matches, it returns an empty list. So, all you need is `return re.findall(regex, string)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the character class and move the word boundary to before matching digits.

```
\bHRB[.,: \w-]*\b(\d+)
```

See the updated [regex](https://regex101.com/r/99y9eG/1)

Or a bit more precise match:

```
\bHRB[,:]?(?:[- ](?:Nr|Nummer)[.:]*)? (\d+)
```

- `\bHRB` Word boundary, then match HRB
- `[,:]?` Optionally match `,` or `:`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[- ](?:Nr|Nummer)[.:]*` Match space or `-`, then Nr or Nummer and 0+ times a . or :
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional
- `(\d+)` Match a space and capture in the first group 1 or more digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U5Gr0q/1)

Comment: How would you add this case to the regex ``HRB Nummer21156``. The desired number is attached to the word `Nummer` or ``Nr.``

Comment: @PParker You could make the space at the end optional https://regex101.com/r/qQl222/1

Comment: Sorry, one more question :) Any idea how to capture this ``HRB 20 7003``. With your regex above I can only capture the first two digits ``20``

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\bHRB\b(?:[-\s]N(?:umme)?r)?[,.:\s]*(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pk5gN0/1)

**Details**

- `\bHRB\b` - a whole word `HRB`
- `(?:[-\s]N(?:umme)?r)?` - an optional group matching `-` or whitespace and then `Nr` or `Nummer`
- `[,.:\s]*` - 0 or more commas, dots, colons or whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Qmbobx):

```
import re

strings = ['HRB 21156','HRB, 1234','HRB: 99887','HRB-Nummer 21156','HRB-Nr. 12345','HRB-Nr: 21156','HRB Nr. 21156','HRB Nr: 21156','HRB Nr.: 21156','HRB Nummer 21156', 'no number here']

def get_company_register_number(string, keyword):
  return re.findall(fr'\b{keyword}\b(?:[-\s]N(?:umme)?r)?[,.:\s]*(\d+)', string)

for s in strings:
  print(s, '=>', get_company_register_number(s, 'HRB'))
```

Output:

```
HRB 21156 => ['21156']
HRB, 1234 => ['1234']
HRB: 99887 => ['99887']
HRB-Nummer 21156 => ['21156']
HRB-Nr. 12345 => ['12345']
HRB-Nr: 21156 => ['21156']
HRB Nr. 21156 => ['21156']
HRB Nr: 21156 => ['21156']
HRB Nr.: 21156 => ['21156']
HRB Nummer 21156 => ['21156']
no number here => []
```