# Update regex to extract company register number

Tags: python, regex

I am extracting the company register number from text using Python regex. In [my demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6AGmq/7) you can see that it works quite well. The regex was constructed using the help from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886756/extract-companies-register-number-in-python-by-getting-the-next-word).
Now I just realized, that the company register number sometimes has a letter "B" at the end. How should I update the regex in order to match this (please see example in my demo).

```
\bHRB[,:]?(?:[- ](?:Nr|Nummer)[.:]*)?\s?(\d+(?: \d+)*)
```

Comment: You can write space + `B`, wrap with a non-capturing group, and add `?` after the group. Add `\b` word boundary if necessary after `B`. Also, `(?:Nr|Nummer)` can be optimized as `N(?:umme)?r`, but people say it is less readable.

Comment: I know that this ``\(+ B\)`` is a capturing group, but I am not sure where exactly to place it. Can you please show it in my example?

Comment: It is not. This is a non-capturing group that I meant: `(?: B)?`. Add at the end.

Comment: Just note that`\(+` in Python `re` means *one or more `(` chars*. `\)` matches a literal `)` char.